# MySQL data structure for questions needing multiple inputs to be true

Tags: mysql, database

Apologies for the title as I'm a bit unsure how to phrase this myself so hopefully an example might help.

I've got a MySQL table that holds questions

```
  question_id, PK Int
  text - Text
```

I also have a table called value that looks like this

```
  value_id, PK Int
  value - varchar
```

I think I might need a mapping table for this along the lines of

```
  question_to_value
  question_id int
  value_id int
```

Though if my example looks like I don't need one then I can change the structure

Basically, given a single or multiple value_ids I want to pick the question that should be asked

so if I am given value_ids 1,2 I should have a unique question_id relating to those ids in the database. Given a value_id of 3 there should be a different question_id, and an input of value_ids (1,2,3) or 1,3 should again retrieve unique question_ids for both permutations.

I'm struggling with how I should go about it. Should I use a) a sort of joining table for this, and b) Most efficient way of querying it.

My initial thought it to have a `question_to_value` table that holds a `question_id` and `value_id` on a 1-1 basis, then doing the following

`select question_id from question WHERE value_id in (?,?,?)` but i'm not sure if this is the optimal way to structure this. Especially as the trouble is using the 'IN' query above if I'm just given the value_id of 1, it would actually bring back all the questions where value_id '1' is the only or part of the group of values to product a particular question. e.g

```
 question_id 1 maps to value 1
 question_id 2 maps to values of 1 and 2.
```

my in statement would bring back question_ids 1 and 2 for a value_id of 1 when I only want question_id 1 as it should match all criteria.

Any ideas on how I should structure this?

*** editing I'm trying to come up with another way of phrasing this to avoid confusion so hopefully the following will help

consider I have 4 'questions'

a
b
c
d

If I'm given an input of 1 I only want to retrieve a.
If I'm given 2 inputs of 1 and 2 I only want to retrieve b.
If I'm given 3 inputs of 1,2,3 I only want to retrieve c.
If I'm given 2 inputs of 1 and 3 I only want to retrieve d.

Comment: your question is very confusing or at least the way you wrote it.Please revise with more samples and your current approach. what you mean by "if I am given value_ids 1,2 I will have [a]?? question_id that should be asked"

Comment: I've tried to tidy it up a bit but as I say I was struggling to explain this myself. The idea is that given a permutation of value_ids I should be able to retrieve a unique question_id. So if I'm given value_ids of 1,2 I can query for the question_id that should be returned if BOTH those values are given. If I'm just gived a value_id of 1, then I should retrieve a different question_id to 1,2 (even though the value_id of 1 is in both queries). Oh and there could be a varying number of value_ids passed in. So in some cases it could be 1, or there could be 3 or 5 say.

Comment: what you mean by "unique". you mean regardless the number of input values, only one question that matches the most should return? In an unique situation more than one distinct question will be returned!

Comment: I mean that I should only ever retrieve one result from the query. As somewhere in my database I want to define that for a particular question I should only retrieve it given values x and y. Similarly if I'm given just value x it will retrieve a different question. The point of my question is i'm struggling to think of the best way to structure this and then put together an efficient query.

Comment: @krishKM does my edit clear things up?

Comment: can you provide the mapping table content for your example abcd questions?

Comment: @krishKM I've updated the question, but I might not need a mapping table if it's not advised. Again the structure is up for question based on the outcome I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to break the problem apart into component parts to define the question in a way that can be expressed in code.

I'm working on the idea that the proper question must match two rules:

1. The question must have an entry for each of the input values
2. The question must not have entries for any other input value

First, consider a query that returns all the value ids for the inputs.

```
SELECT value_id from values where `value` IN <inputs>
```

I don't know what language you are using, so I can't tell you how to build the inputs list. In php, it would be something like:

```
"('" . implode("','" $inputs) . "')"
```

to properly wrap each option in quotes (assuming the values don't also have quotes, but that's a separate, language-specific problem to solve).

Now it is simple to use that query to create a query that returns questions that have ANY of the input values:

```
SELECT question_id 
    FROM mapping_table 
    WHERE value_id IN (SELECT value_id from values where `value` IN <inputs>)
```

Finally, we can tweak that query to only return the question_ids with the right number of matches. We want one row for each question, and we only want questions that match all the values:

```
SELECT question_id 
    FROM mapping_table 
    WHERE value_id IN (SELECT value_id from values where `value` IN <inputs>)
    GROUP BY question_id
    HAVING COUNT(question_id) = <number of inputs>
```

That will give you a list of question_ids that match constraint 1 above. It will not test for constraint 2 in every case; if the input is (1,2) then this will match the question for (1,2) and the question for (1,2,3).

However, if you only get one row back from this query, there is no need to filter that list with the second query.

If you did get more than one match for the above, the second query is pretty simple - it's similar to the above query but with a different WHERE clause. This will get all the mapping table entries for the ids from the first query, and match the ones that don't have any extras:

```
SELECT question_id
    FROM mapping_table
    WHERE question_id IN <ids from first query>
    GROUP BY question_id
    HAVING COUNT(question_id) = <number of inputs>
```

You could combine the two queries, but unless performance is an issue, I'd keep them separate to make things easier to maintain.

NOTE: there is nothing here to constrain your data to make sure it is valid. In other words, there's nothing to prevent two questions from matching (1,2) when the questions are added to the database.